# Keycloak: Add common attributes to user account information

Tags: keycloak

In Keycloak, I see a lot of built-ins like phone. How do I add them(e.g. phone) to my account profile page as shown below(e.g. below Last name)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create custom account theme and override `account.ftl` template.

Read through [Theme creation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes) and [Custom User Attributes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#account-management-console) documentation pages.